# Using python to determine if an image should be saved as bitonal tiff or color jp2

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a bunch of scanned pages from books and need an automatic way to determine if the page should be bitonal tiff or color jp2. If a page is just text and black and white charts, it would be converted to a bitonal tiff.  If a page has a color image on it or highlights or something, then it would be a color jp2.  I have some examples:

Black and white examples:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN0lh.jpg) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SGDp.jpg) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZkrH.jpg) [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1efow.jpg) [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y29Z3.jpg)

Color examples:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DSsX.jpg) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFFVF.jpg) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T6GX.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following naive, rule-based approach (code is at the bottom). What it does is it reads the image using the `PIL` package, gets the pixels' `RGB` values and if the absolute difference between `R` and `G`, `R` and `B` and `G` and `B` is below 35 (which I just defined as an example), it is considered a grayscale, black-and-white pixel. Else, it would be a colored pixel. In my rule-based approach, if more than 5% of the image is composed of colored pixels, then I consider the image to be a `color jp2`, else it is a `bitonal tiff`.

I have tried for your sample images, and it misclassified the 5th bitonal tiff image (possibly because the image is a bit yellow-ish, so you would need to create a rule for those) and the 2nd color jp2 image (which has really dark colors, which can trick my grayscale rule):

[image]

Following a rule-based approach would lead you to reasonably good results, but can be cumbersome to account for all cases. What you could do, on the other hand, is use a supervised machine learning model where you feed it with the labels (whether the image is a bitonal tiff or a colored jp2) and the `RGB` vector of the image, train it and see if it yields good results. It will probably not have 100% accuracy, but will be better than trying to figure the best rule-based approach manually, although it would be more work. Now it is up to you to figure out how accurate you want to be.

```
from PIL import Image

def process_image(filename):

    image = Image.open(filename)
    width, height = image.size
    pixel_grid = image.load()

    colored_rgbs_count = 0

    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            r, g, b = pixel_grid[i,j]
            if abs(r - g) > 35 or abs(r - b) > 35 or abs(b - g) > 35:
                colored_rgbs_count += 1
            
    return 'color jp2' if colored_rgbs_count > width * height * 0.05 else 'bitonal tiff'

print(f'bitonal_1: {process_image("bitonal_1.jpg")}')
print(f'bitonal_2: {process_image("bitonal_2.jpg")}')
print(f'bitonal_3: {process_image("bitonal_3.jpg")}')
print(f'bitonal_4: {process_image("bitonal_4.jpg")}')
print(f'bitonal_5: {process_image("bitonal_5.jpg")}')

print(f'color_1: {process_image("color_1.jpg")}')
print(f'color_2: {process_image("color_2.jpg")}')
print(f'color_3: {process_image("color_3.jpg")}')
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help and the tips on machine learning.  I have zero experience in that so it may take me a little bit to get up to speed.  I'll give this code a shot and hopefully be able to tweak it enough for my needs.

Comment: Just a thought, would PIL be able to convert to a 8-color palette with "Bayer" dithering?  I've been using XnConvert and it has that option which can kinda work for that tinted page.  Then based off those values, I wonder if it can get more accurate?